# How to output result inside readonly input field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Got stuck from google and some documentation, so what I want is to output 3 value input fields:

1. `id="yourname"`
2. `id="lockerid"`
3. `id="secret"`

inside readonly field `id="randomidresult"`. So when I click button generate, output field will be result like this :

`Name-1234-SomeRandomString`

But still no luck, Here's the code :

```js
        function goBack() {
            window.history.back();
        }

        function secret() {
            var text = "";
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            }
            return text;
        }    
        
        function getValue() {
            var randomidresult = document.getElementById("randomidresult");
            var yourname = document.getElementById("yourname").value;
            var lockerid = document.getElementById("lockerid").value;
            var secretcode = secret();.value;
            randomidresult.innerHTML = + yourname + "-" + lockerid + "-" secretcode;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:rgb(218,218,218);">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Random Student Generator</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<section id="id-generator" style="padding:40px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" id="title-generator">
                <h1>Please create your Random ID Here</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="input-yourname">
                <label>Input Your Name</label>
                <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="yourname" required="" id="yourname" style="width:75%;">
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="input-locker-id">
                <label>Input Your Locker ID</label>
                <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="lockerid" required="" id="lockerid" style="width:75%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="secret" id="secret">
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="generate" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="getValue()">Generate ID</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="result-generator" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <label>Your Random Student Identifier Result :</label>
                <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="result" id="randomidresult" style="width:75%;" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="copy-id" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button">Copy Generated ID</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="go-back" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="goBack()">Go Back To Previous Site</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please, learn how to debug your code: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp
Your problem is totally caused by typos and JS errors that can be easily fixed if you debug correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `input` does not have `innerHTML`; it has a `value`. You had a few typos in your code, including: `var secretcode = secret();.value;` (it should be `var secretcode = secret();` since the return value of `secret()` is already a String and you have an extra semicolon) and `randomidresult.innerHTML = + yourname + "-" + lockerid + "-" secretcode;` (it should be `randomidresult.value = + yourname  "-" + lockerid + "-" +secretcode;` as you have an extra `+` symbol and are missing a `+` symbol in front of `secretcode` to concatenate it to the String).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:rgb(218,218,218);">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Random Student Generator</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<section id="id-generator" style="padding:40px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" id="title-generator">
                <h1>Please create your Random ID Here</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="input-yourname">
                <label>Input Your Name</label>
                <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="yourname" required="" id="yourname" style="width:75%;">
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="input-locker-id">
                <label>Input Your Locker ID</label>
                <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="lockerid" required="" id="lockerid" style="width:75%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="secret" id="secret">
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="generate" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="getValue()">Generate ID</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="result-generator" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <label>Your Random Student Identifier Result :</label>
                <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="result" id="randomidresult" style="width:75%;" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="copy-id" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button">Copy Generated ID</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="go-back" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="goBack()">Go Back To Previous Site</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
 function goBack() {
            window.history.back();
        }

        function secret() {
            var text = "";
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            }
            return text;
        }    
        
        function getValue() {
            var randomidresult = document.getElementById("randomidresult");
            var yourname = document.getElementById("yourname").value;
            var lockerid = document.getElementById("lockerid").value;
            var secretcode = secret();
            randomidresult.value =  yourname + "-" + lockerid + "-" + secretcode;
        }
</script>
```

To copy the generated ID, you can create a `textarea` with the value of the `input` with the generated ID to select and execute the copy command and remove thereafter.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:rgb(218,218,218);">
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Random Student Generator</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<section id="id-generator" style="padding:40px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" id="title-generator">
                <h1>Please create your Random ID Here</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="input-yourname">
                <label>Input Your Name</label>
                <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="yourname" required="" id="yourname" style="width:75%;">
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="input-locker-id">
                <label>Input Your Locker ID</label>
                <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="lockerid" required="" id="lockerid" style="width:75%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="secret" id="secret">
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="generate" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="getValue()">Generate ID</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="result-generator" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <label>Your Random Student Identifier Result :</label>
                <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="result" id="randomidresult" style="width:75%;" readonly>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="copy-id" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" onClick="copy(document.getElementById('randomidresult').value)">Copy Generated ID</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12" id="go-back" style="margin-top:20px;">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="goBack()">Go Back To Previous Site</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script>
 function goBack() {
            window.history.back();
        }

        function secret() {
            var text = "";
            var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            }
            return text;
        }    
        
        function getValue() {
            var randomidresult = document.getElementById("randomidresult");
            var yourname = document.getElementById("yourname").value;
            var lockerid = document.getElementById("lockerid").value;
            var secretcode = secret();
            randomidresult.value =  yourname + "-" + lockerid + "-" + secretcode;
        }
        function copy(val){
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value =  val;
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
   textArea.remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: cool it works now, many thanks, so how do i get learn about different innerHtml and value? many thanks again.

Comment: @artasena `innerHTML` is the HTML inside an element. There is no HTML inside an `input`, but there is HTML inside all other elements like such: `<div>This<span> is the HTML inside the div element</span>.</div>`

Answer (score -1):

Some typos in your code that caused syntax error.

Also you need to use `randomidresult.value` instead of `randomidresult.innerHTML`

```js
function goBack() {
        window.history.back();
    }

    function secret() {
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }
        return text;
    }    
    
    function getValue() {
        var randomidresult = document.getElementById("randomidresult");
        var yourname = document.getElementById("yourname").value;
        var lockerid = document.getElementById("lockerid").value;
        var secretcode = secret();
        randomidresult.value = yourname + "-" + lockerid + "-" + secretcode;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Random Student Identifier</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/Footer-Dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">

    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:rgb(218,218,218);">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Random Student Generator</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section id="id-generator" style="padding:40px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" id="title-generator">
                    <h1>Please create your Random ID Here</h1>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-12" id="input-yourname">
                    <label>Input Your Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="yourname" required="" id="yourname" style="width:75%;">
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-12" id="input-locker-id">
                    <label>Input Your Locker ID</label>
                    <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="lockerid" required="" id="lockerid" style="width:75%;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="secret" id="secret">
                </div>

                <div class="col-12" id="generate" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="getValue()">Generate ID</button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-12" id="result-generator" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <label>Your Random Student Identifier Result :</label>
                    <input class="form-control-lg d-block" type="text" name="result" id="randomidresult" style="width:75%;" readonly>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-12" id="copy-id" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button">Copy Generated ID</button>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-12" id="go-back" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="goBack()">Go Back To Previous Site</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just change back to `var secretcode = secret();` is fine. I've updated the Snippet.